# How to deal with dot in an url path in writing service

Tags: java, url, service

I am writing a "GET" endpoint looks like following:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{configSetId}/{version}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = { "application/json" })
public ResponseEntity<List<Metadata>> getMetadatasByConfigSetIdAndVersion(
        @PathVariable("configSetId") final String configSetId,
        @PathVariable("version") final String version) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(metadataService.getMetadatasByConfigSetIdAndVersion(configSetId, version));
}
```

So I can send a "GET" request to localhost:8080/{configSetId}/{version}, for example: localhost:8080/configSet1/v1

But the problem is if the version is "v1.02", then the ".02" will be ignored and the version I got is v1. How can I avoid this behaivor? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since "." is special character so don't use it directly on your request.

Instead of

```
v1.02
```

Just try

```
v1%2E02
```

Where %2E is URL encoding of ".". 
For more information, please refer to this link [HTML URL Encoding](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)